# Javascript array higher-order functions

Tags: javascript, arrays, higher-order-functions

Can anyone explain to me how this code works? I looked for `reduce` and `concat` functions in Array, I understand these functions but I don't understand how this code works initialy:

```js
var arrays = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6]];
    
console.log(arrays.reduce(function(flat, current) {
   return flat.concat(current);
}, []));
// → [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: it migh be helpful to instead of, `function(flat, current)...` think of `function(akkumulator,nextItem)...`

Answer (score 1):

Well actually it's a wrong use of `.reduce()`. For this job you don't need no initial array. Just the previous (`p`) and current (`c`) hand to hand can do it. Such as;

```js
var arrays = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6]];
    
console.log(arrays.reduce((p,c) => p.concat(c)));
```

Note: Initial is handy when the type of the returned value is different from the array items. However in this case you are processing arrays and returning an array which renders the use of initial redundant.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a `console.log` inside the callback we pass to the `reduce` and think about the output:

```js
var arrays = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6]];

console.log(arrays.reduce(function(flat, current) {
  console.log('flat: '+ flat + 'current: ' + current)
  return flat.concat(current);
}, []));
```

Initially we concat an empty array and the array [1,2,3]. So the result is a new array with elements [1,2,3]. Then we concat this array with the next element of the `arrays`, the array [4,5]. So the result would be a new array with elements [1,2,3,4,5]. Last we concat this array with the last element of the `arrays`, the `array` [6]. Hence the result is the array [1,2,3,4,5,6].

Ir order to understand in details the above you have to read about [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

As it is stated in the above link:

> The reduce() method applies a function against an accumulator and each
>   value of the array (from left-to-right) to reduce it to a single value

Furthermore the syntax is

```
arr.reduce(callback, [initialValue])
```

In you case the initialValue is an empty array, `[]`.

Answer (score 0):

I've described each step for you.

```js
var arrays = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6]];

console.log(arrays.reduce(function(flat, current) {
  
  // first loop: flat - [1,2,3], current - [4,5]
  // [1,2,3].concat([4,5]) -> [1,2,3,4,5]
  
  //second/last loop: flat - [1,2,3,4,5], current - [6]
  // [1,2,3,4,5].concat([6]) -> [1,2,3,4,5,6]
  
  //function stop

  return flat.concat(current);
}, []));
```

Comment: The first loop would be `flat - [] & current - [1,2,3]`, right?

Comment: flat - [ ] why?

Comment: @Bhavik Well, the first loop will be actually `flat - [1,2,3] & current - [4,5]`.

Comment: then why in the end of function has [ ] ?

Comment: @Sahil Sahilov It's not needed.

Comment: @SahilSahilov It's an optional argument, used as the first argument to the first call of the callback. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Comment: @SahilSahilov `Value to use as the first argument to the first call of the callback.` [mdn array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Comment: @SahilSahilov As I have mentioned in my answer the initial argument is useful when there is a type change between the processed array items and the returned result. However it's not the case in this example. You process arrays and return an array.

Comment: @Redu Exactly. In this case it's unnecessary.

Comment: @Kinduser , I understand wih reading this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce    [ ] this accumulator

Answer (score 0):

So assuming we have the 2D array that you do: `[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6]]` that is being reduced, the function is split into 2 main components.

```
array.reduce((accumulator, iterator) => {...}, initialValue);
```

- `flat` - this is the accumulator of the reduction. It is given the initial value as passed into the second parameter of the `reduce` function and is used to store the values as the iterator passes through them.
- `current` - this is the iterator that goes through all values within the data set being reduced.

So as you're iterating through the data set, your example is concatenating the accumulation array with the current value, and by the end you have your new array.

Answer (score 0):

`Array.reduce` expects a callback with following signature:

> function(previousElement, currentElement, index, array)

and an optional initial value.

In first iteration, if `initialValue` is passed, then `previousElement` will hold this value and `currentElement` will hold `firstArrayElement.

If not, then `previousElement` will hold `firstArrayElement` and `currentElement` will hold `secondArrayElement`.

For the following iterations, `previousElement` will hold value returned by previous iteration and `currentElement` will hold next value.

---

So in you example, initially `flat` holds `[]`.

`return flat.concat(current);` will return a new merged array. This value will be used as `flat` for next iteration, and this process is returned. Finally, value returned by last iteration is used as final return value and is printed in console.